# AJAX request with event delegation on parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey I'm generating some dynamic `HTML` form with `javscript` and to listen event on it I'm using event `delegation` in the parent element.And it works so far properly.But now when I want to submit a form with `ajax` I'm not getting a way to get out of it.

## HTML - updateForm is parent here

```
<form id="updateForm" class="py-3" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <button id="swipe" class="bg-btn hidden-lg-up swipe_btn" style="font-size:1em; float:left;"><i class="fa fa-align-right swipe_btn"></i></button>
            <div class="row" style="clear:both;">
                <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
                    <img src="https://unsplash.it/100/100" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                    <label for="upload" class="btn-update"><i class="fa fa-camera"></i></label>
                    <input type="file" name="profilePic" class="upload" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
                    <span>Ashish Mehra</span>
                    <b>@</b>
                    <p class="lead"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-11 col-md-12 mx-auto">
                    <input type="text" name="fullname" value="Ashish Mehra" class="form-control">

                    <input type="text" name="username" value="" class="form-control">

                    <textarea name="bio" class="form-control" maxlength="120"></textarea>

                    <button type="button" class="bg-btn btn-save" name="button">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

## Javascript

```
 swipeForm.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
  if(e.target.classList.contains('btn-update')) showDialog();
  if(e.target.classList.contains('btn-save'))  swipeForm.submit();
  if(!e.target.classList.contains('swipe_btn')) return;
  e.preventDefault();
  swipeForm.classList.toggle('swipe');
  swipe_panel.classList.toggle('index');
});
```

So when the click on form is on element with **btn-save** class at that time I want to fire submit event and want to make `AJAX request` as well.

Comment: You should write `document.getElementByClass("btn-save").addEventListener("click", myFunction);` where myFunction is the function to do the ajax requests

Comment: what is "swipeForm" here? Also, calling "submit" will normally cause a postback, not an ajax call, unless you have handled the "submit" event of the form, and overriden the default behaviour. I can't see any code which suggests that you have done this.